# Make multiple changes with XLST 1.0 (uppercase element first letter, order elements, aggrate/group elements)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

My input xml looks something like this:

```
<myFamily>
  <spouse type="1">Halle Berry</spouse>
  <parent type="bio">Jane Smith-Doe</parent>
  <spouse type="2">Eva Longoria</spouse>
  <uncle type="paternal">Bob Beam</uncle>
  <parent type="bio">Jim Beam</parent>
  <uncle type="maternal">Mike Smith</uncle>
  <aunt type="paternal">Viola Davis</aunt>
  <inLaw type="mother">Dr. Curry-Pepper</inLaw>
  <brother name="Ron Isley">
    <child>Sara Isley</child>
    <child>Ron Isley Jr.</child>
    <child>Martha Isley-Focker</child>
  </brother>
  <parent type="step">Jon Doe</parent>
  <inLaw type="father">Dr. Pepper</inLaw>
  <spouse type="3">Sofia Vergara</spouse>
  <uncle type="paternal">Bo Beam</uncle>
  <spouse type="3">Sonya Curry</spouse>
  <Sister name ="Shelly Isley"/>
</myFamily>
```

I want it to end up like this:

```
<MyFamily>
  <Parents>
    <Parent type="bio">Jane Smith-Doe</Parent>
    <Parent type="bio">Jim Beam</Parent>
    <Parent type="step">Jon Doe</Parent>
  </Parents>
  <Siblings>
    <Sister name ="Shelly Isley"/>
    <Brother name="Ron Isley">
      <Child>Sara Isley</Child>
      <Child>Ron Isley Jr.</Child>
      <Child>Martha Isley-Focker</Child>
    </Brother>
  <Siblings>
  <Uncles>
    <Uncle type="paternal">Bob Beam</Uncle>
    <Uncle type="maternal">Mike Smith</Uncle>
    <Uncle type="paternal">Bo Beam</Uncle>  
  </Uncles>
  <Aunts><Aunt type="paternal">Viola Davis</Aunt><Aunts>
  <InLaws>
    <InLaw type="mother">Dr. Curry-Pepper</InLaw>
    <InLaw type="father">Dr. Pepper</InLaw>
  </InLaws>
  <Wives>
    <Wife type="1">Halle Berry</Wife>
    <Wife type="2">Eva Longoria</Wife>
    <Wife type="3">Sofia Vergara</Wife>
    <Wife type="3">Sonya Curry</Wife>
  </Wives>
</MyFamily>
```

To make the first letter uppercase, rename the spouse, and have it ordered a certain way I tried this and it didn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Order Section Nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'parent')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'sister')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'brother')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'unle')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'aunt')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'inLaw')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myFamily[(SectionName = 'spouse')]" mode="nodeCopy"/>
        <!-- List All Remaining Nodes and Remove ones that have already been ordered above -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(parent | sister | brother |  spouse | uncle | aunt | inLaw)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Rename spouse Nodes -->
<xsl:template match="spouse">
  <Wife><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="nodeCopy"/></Wife>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Uppercase first letter of elements -->
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{concat(
                        translate(subsstring(name(.),1,1), $vLower, $vUpper),
                        substring(name(.), 2, string-length(name(.))-1)
                      )}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

With regards to the way I want to group it, I feel like this might apply (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16818842/5517100), but I don't understand it.  Honestly, I barely understand any of it.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. WRT understanding XSLT 1.0 grouping, I suggest you read this: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Although with pre-defined groups you may not need it.

Comment: Your desired result is not well-formed due to mismatches of title case (i.e., `<Child>Sara Isley</child>`). Remember XML is case sensitive. And why is `<Aunt>` title case but not `<uncle>`? How generalizable a solution are you looking for? Will spouses always be wives? Why not just retrieve nodes by those root sections (i.e., all parents, all siblings, etc.)? This feels like a coursework problem.

Comment: Oops....meant to have em match the uppercase. It was a cut and paste fail

Answer (score 2):

With pre-defined groups as shown in your example, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/myFamily">
    <MyFamily>
        <Parents>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="parent"/>
        </Parents>
        <Siblings>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="brother | sister"/>
        </Siblings>
        
        <!-- continue for other groups -->
        
    </MyFamily>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer to omit empty groups:

```
<xsl:template match="/myFamily">
    <MyFamily>
        <xsl:variable name="parents" select="parent" />
        <xsl:if test="$parents">
            <Parents>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$parents"/>
            </Parents>
        </xsl:if>
        
        <!-- continue for other groups -->
        
    </MyFamily>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That helps a lot. Can't believe I didn't think of that. How do I make the nested elements uppercase too? There are way too many to use this approach. This answer would change <brother> to <Brother>, but it wouldn't fix <child>. That's why I was trying that concat with the translate. Still, this is a big help.

Comment: Just add another template matching `*` - the same as the last one in your stylesheet.